# C++ - Error C2511: overloaded member function not found in 'BMI'

Tags: c++

Got an error on my C++ program. It is likely to be something simple as I have only just started programming.

The error is:

```
Error   1   error C2511: 'void BMI::getWeight(double)' : overloaded member function not found in 'BMI'  c:\users\**********\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project2\project2\bmi.cpp 40  1   Project2
```

[bmi.h](http://pastebin.com/57hZnvvb):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef BMI_H
#define BMI_H

class BMI {
public:
    //Defualt Constructor
    BMI();

    //Overload Constructor
    BMI(string, int, double);

    //Destructor
    ~BMI();

    //Accessor Functions
    string getName() const;
        // getName - returns name of paitent

    int getHeight() const;
        //getHeight - returns height of paitent

    double getWeight() const;
        //getWeight returns weight of paitent


private:
    //Member Variables
    string newName;
    int newHeight;
    double newWeight;
};

#endif
```

[bmi.cpp](http://pastebin.com/1mqcvzxS):

```
// Function Definitions
#include "BMI.h"

BMI::BMI() {
  newHeight = 0;
  newWeight = 0.0;
}

BMI::BMI(string name, int height, double weight) {
  newName = name;
  newHeight = height;
  newWeight = weight;
}

BMI::~BMI() {

}

string BMI::getName() const {
  return newName;
}

int BMI::getHeight() const {
  return newHeight;
}

double BMI::getWeight() const {
  return newWeight;
}

void BMI::setName(string name) {
  newName = name;
}

void BMI::setHeight(int height) {
  newHeight = height;
}

void BMI::setWeight(double weight) {
  newWeight = weight;
}
```

Comment: Where is your header file?

Comment: Two thoughts: include your header file, and put out the shortest possible program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry @OldProgrammer, I forgot to include it, just posted it to pastebin here - http://pastebin.com/57hZnvvb

Comment: Please **never** put a using directive in a header.

Comment: You don't seem to have defined any setters in your header.

Comment: Unless I am blind, there is no such function, 'void BMI::getWeight(double),  declared in your header or cpp file posted.

Comment: @OldProgrammer nor is there one invoked on line 40...

Comment: @OldProgrammer getting old, huh? (i don't see it either though)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, when I try to compile the code I see a couple of problems:

- The setName(string) function in the .cpp doesn't match anything in the header.
- The setHeight(int) function in the .cpp doesn't match anything in the header.
- The setWeight(double) function in the .cpp doesn't match anything in the header.

I would try to solve the compilation errors in the order they occur, and then see if you still have a problem with getWeight. I'm assuming that you are seeing the same problems with the undeclared functions that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be telling you that you are trying to call `BMI::getWeight()` somewhere and you are passing in it a parameter with a `double` type. This error is a bit perplexing as no such function that matches `void BMI::getWeight(double)` defined in either the BMI class in the header file or the cpp file. If you have changed the code since you posted it up then please do update and post ALL of the compiler messages. I suspect that you have not posted all of the compiler messages because `SetName`,`setHeight` and `setWeight` are all missing from the BMI class definition. So make sure you add all of those into the BMI class.

Also I think that it's good practice to initialize your data members differently. So instead of:

```
BMI::BMI(string name, int height, double weight) {
  newName = name;
  newHeight = height;
  newWeight = weight;
}
```

you should prefer:

```
BMI::BMI(string name, int height, double weight):
  newName(name),
  newHeight(height),
  newWeight(weight)
{ }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have only started reading about c++ for a few days and gave it a go today. Its very hard compared to python..

Comment: @moakeseey, c++ is a big language and very easy to write bad code in if you don't follow good conventions. Did you end up getting this code to compile correctly?

Comment: yeah I did, I shut of visual studio and then opened it up again and it worked again, it might of been an error that stuck, but it was all working again.